# Let $u(x,y)$ be harmonic in a connected region $D$ and $u = 0$ on a non empty open subset of $D$. Show that $u = 0$ on $D$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the function $f(z) = u_x-iu_y$, by the Cauchy Riemann equations, one immediately observes that $f$ is analytic in the open connected set $D$. In the open subset domain $D_1 \subset D$, we have $u = 0$, hence $u_x = u_y = 0$ inside $D_1$. Thus $f$ is equals to $0$ inside $D_1$. By uniqueness theorem $f = 0$ inside $D$. It follows that $u_x = u_y = 0$ as well in $D$. $u$ is a constant in $D$, in particular, $u$ is analytic in $D$. And since $u$ is equals to $0$ inside $D_1$, by uniqueness Theorem again, we have $u = 0 $ inside $D$.

**Will my answer above be correct?**

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Hi there, would my corrected version be correct?

Comment: Hum, it *is* technically correct, but it kind of misses the point I guess? In a sense you've simply quoted uniqueness for harmonic functions, but translated via complex analysis. This is 'bad' because: $(1)$ you don't get to see what's behind it; $(2)$ it does not generalize for harmonic functions of $n\geq 3$ variables (the complex analysis analogue does not apply).

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Hi, would appreciate you to give me more insights on this. I have just finished my part I of complex analysis .

Comment: If this question was asked in the context of a complex analysis course, then the answer is perfectly fine. If this question was asked in the context of a harmonic analysis course, then the answer is lacking (imo).

Comment: It is asked in the context of complex analysis. But i do see Harmonic functions is a big part of it.

Comment: Then the answer is good. That said, if you're interested in harmonic analysis, you will be pleased to see many deep results of complex analysis are actually 'complex versions' of properties of harmonic functions. For instance, Cauchy's integral formula is just the mean value property of harmonic functions. Similar analogues exist for analycity, the maximum modulus principle, or Liouville's theorem.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri thanks for the insight!